# Can this be said this way?

Tags: meaning

“I believe this machine works so you need to prove my theory”. I want to say that I am not sure that the machine works and you need to check it. Can I say “I believe” or do I need to use “I think this machine...”?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this. Why would she, he, or they, need to prove YOUR theory based on the functionality of some machine?

Comment: It’s just an example, let’s replace “you” to “I”. I just want to know whether I can use “I believe “ and then say that something should be proven

Comment: Yes, you can say *believe*. You can also say *think*. Or a dozen other things. That is not the problem with the sentence. The problem with the sentence is everything else. You will need to rewrite it.

Comment: What do you think about this “I believe this machine works. Let’s try to run it” ?

Comment: *I believe this machine works. Let's test it and see.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking the difference between "I believe the machine works" and "I think the machine works." Those mean the same.

If you are not sure it works you can say, "I believe you, that you think it really works, but I need to see it work to believe it myself.